# How to automatically close all the terminal buffers when closing vim with :qa?

Tags: vimscript, filetype, vim9script

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically force-wipe all the running terminals when quitting Vim with `:qa`.

My attempt (that does not work):

```
vim9script

def WipeoutTerminals()
    for buf_nr in term_list()
        exe "bw! " .. buf_nr
    endfor
enddef

augroup shoutoff_terminals
    autocmd VimLeave * call WipeoutTerminals()
augroup END
```

Comment: How about `:qa!`?

Comment: That may be dangerous as I may errononeously close some non-written buffer, thus losing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`QuitPre`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#QuitPre) or [`ExitPre`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#ExitPre) instead of `VimLeave`

Doc says

> Can be used to close any non-essential window

```
vim9script

def WipeoutTerminals()
    for buf_nr in term_list()
        exe "bw! " .. buf_nr
    endfor
enddef

augroup shoutoff_terminals
    autocmd QuitPre * call WipeoutTerminals()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I did to leave automatically the "side bar".

Defined here as:

- The terminal
- The quickfix window
- The NERDTree side bar

```vimscript
function! IsSideBar(buf_nr)
" Return 1 if the buffer correspond to a side bar: "
" - A terminal window "
" - The quickfix window "
" - The NERDTree side bar "
" - ... "
  let buf_name = bufname(a:buf_nr)
  let buf_type = getbufvar(a:buf_nr, '&filetype')
  let readonly = getbufvar(a:buf_nr, '&readonly')

  if !has('nvim')
    " Neovim doesn't support the term_list function "
    let term_buffers = term_list()
  else
    let term_buffers = []
  endif

  if buf_type ==# 'qf'
    " QuickFix, LocationList: "
    " Not Read Only "
    echom 'QuickFix'
    return 1

  " There are situation where the only buffer you have is help and you are "
  elseif buf_type ==# 'nerdtree'
    " Read Only "
    " echom 'NerdTree' "
    return 1

  elseif index(term_buffers, a:buf_nr) >= 0
    " echom 'Console' "
    return 1

  else
    return 0

  endif
endfunction

function! LeaveSideBar()
  " Go to a non side bar window "
  let loop = 0
  while 1
    let loop = loop + 1
    let bufnr = bufnr('%')

    if loop > 10
      " Don't search for more than 10 windows "
      " To handle the case all the windows are 'side bars' "
      break
    endif

    if IsSideBar(bufnr)
      wincmd w
    else
      break
    endif

  endwhile
endfunction

command! LeaveSideBar call LeaveSideBar()

function! GetNumWindows()
  let num_windows = 0

  " echom 'winnr($):' .. winnr('$') "

  for win_nr in range(1, winnr('$'))
    let buf_nr = winbufnr(win_nr)
    " echom "Analyze buffer: " . buf_nr "
    if IsSideBar(buf_nr)
      continue
    endif
    let num_windows = num_windows + 1
  endfor

  " echom 'Num Windows: ' . num_windows "
  return num_windows
endfunction

function! KillSideBars()
  let num_windows = GetNumWindows()
  " echom "Num windows: " . num_windows "
  if num_windows > 0
    " If there are non side bar windows do nothing "
    return
  endif

  " Debug "
  " return "

  " Delete the terminal buffers that don't correspond to a window "
  let term_buffers = term_list()
  for buf_nr in term_buffers
    " echom "what about terminal: " . buf_nr "
    if len(win_findbuf(buf_nr)) == 0
      " echom "delete terminal: " . buf_nr "
      execute 'bd! ' . buf_nr
    endif
  endfor

  let term_buffers = term_list()
  let buf_nr = bufnr('%')
  " echom "buffer: " . buf_nr "
  if index(term_buffers, buf_nr) >= 0
    " Kill the terminal buffer and quit "
    " echom "terminal buffer" "
    call feedkeys("\<C-w>:bd!\<CR>:quit\<CR>:\<BS>")
  endif
endfunction

" Close Vim if the last buffer is side bar: "
autocmd BufEnter * call KillSideBars()
```

I should adapt it for `:qa` but it quits Vim when the last buffer visible are side bars (it kill the terminals visible or not and the remaining side bars).